# Match multiple substrings and concatenate

Tags: php, regex

Given I have

```
KsKd2s4dAs =AhAd2s4dKs =AsAd2s4dKs 5s5d6s6d2c AsAd6s6d2c =AdQdKdJdTd =AhQhKhJhTh =AsQsKsJsTs
```

I want to match all the substrings starting with '=' and concatenate them with this sign.

Output should be

```
KsKd2s4dAs AhAd2s4dKs=AsAd2s4dKs 5s5d6s6d2c AsAd6s6d2c AdQdKdJdTd=AhQhKhJhTh=AsQsKsJsTs
```

I am able to capture by using this regexp `(=.{10}\s?)+` but failing to find a convenient way to make such string.

Comment: you need more code after getting strings with regexp

Comment: Why are the last three groups joined together with the `=` character, when the previous three groups are separated with whitespace?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica there are 3 groups in the end, 2 near the beginning. Sorry I do not understand the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)\s+(?==)|(?<!\S)=)(\S+)~', '$1', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUMoku/1/). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s+(?==)|(?<!\S)=)` - either a `=` char at the start of string or right after a whitespace or the end of the previous match and then one or more whitespaces followed with a `=` char
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars.

Another way is using `preg_replace_callback`:

```php
$text = 'KsKd2s4dAs =AhAd2s4dKs =AsAd2s4dKs 5s5d6s6d2c AsAd6s6d2c =AdQdKdJdTd =AhQhKhJhTh =AsQsKsJsTs';
echo preg_replace_callback('~=(\S+(?:\s+=\S+)*)~', function($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $m[1]);
}, $text);
```

See [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ZQbVl) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUMoku/2).

The `=(\S+(?:\s+=\S+)*)` matches a `=` and then captures into Group 1 any one or more non-whitespaces followed with zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces, `=`, and one or more non-whitespaces.